# Actualización de tabla con la fecha más reciente

Tags: php, mysql

Hola Buen Día tengan todos realizo unas actualizaciones de una tabla pero me he encontrado un detalle y no se como solucionarlo.

Tengo una **tabla1** que contiene:

```
 ________________________________________
|   ID    Nombre    Apellido    Fecha    |
|________________________________________|  
|    1     Alma      Perez               |
|                                        |
|    2     Norma     Sanchez             |
|                                        |
|    3     Axel      Jimenez             |
|________________________________________|
```

y **tabla2** con:

```
 _____________________   
|    ID      Fecha    |
|_____________________|   
|    1    2019/03/1   |
|                     |
|    1    2019/03/5   |
|                     |
|    1    2019/03/19  |
|                     |
|    2    2019/03/17  |
|                     |
|    2    2019/03/21  |
|                     |
|    2    2019/03/22  |
|                     |
|    3    2019/03/5   |
|                     |
|    3    2019/03/16  |
|                     |
|    3    2019/03/27  |
|_____________________|
```

Y actualizo con la siguiente consulta pero me genera error

```
$actualizar = "UPDATE tabla1 AS t1 INNER JOIN tabla2 AS T2 ON t1.ID = T2.ID SET t1.Fecha = t2.Fecha"
```

**Resultado esperado:**

```
_________________________________________
|                                        |
|   ID    Nombre    Apellido    Fecha    |
|________________________________________|
|   1     Alma      Perez     2019/03/19 |
|                                        |
|   2     Norma     Sanchez   2019/03/22 |
|                                        |
|   3     Axel      Jimenez   2019/03/27 |
|________________________________________|
```

Me pueden asesorar entiendo que le puede falta una condición a mi consulta.

GRACIAS :3

Answer (score 0):

puedes empezar obteniendo el máximo valor de la fecha del registro de la tabla2 que este relacionado con tu registro de la tabla1, puede que aplique solo en el caso que exista la relación entre todos los registros.

ejemplo:

```
UPDATE tabla1 set tabla1.Fecha =(select max(tabla2.Fecha) as fecha from tabla2 where tabla2.ID = tabla1.ID)
```

Comment: Por favor, modifica la pregunta e incorpora la estructura de las tablas en SQL con algún registro para las pruebas (phpMyAdmin,Exportar) y así podamos montar un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).